# Data Warehousing GUID to Int PrimaryKeys

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

I'm a (very) junior Analyst responsible for setting up an mssql DWH which hosts data from our CRM for reporting purposes.

The current CRM uses uniqueidentifiers in its mssql database for all keys, and some of the tables have 8m+ rows. In our reporting software (Qlikview) I can swap the GUIDs for ints and take an 800mb data file down to 90mb which is excellent, however I'd like to perform this logic in the DWH if possible to make it faster and a little cleaner.

My issue is I have no idea how to do so while maintaining FK links to other tables. I have considered maintaining a staging table of GUIDs and associated numeric IDs however this seems inefficient and poses a problem of then trying to write some arbitrary numeric ID to the PK column of the destination table which I'm sure is a terrible idea.

The DWH import works as follows: I have USPs on the source db performing SELECTs which are executed by a SSIS package, the output of which are placed in tables of the same name on the [Staging] schema of the DWH. From there, transform is performed by USPs on the DWH, also executed by the same SSIS package, which handles execution order and multi-threading. Whatever implementation I come up with will need to be compatible with this architecture (done within USPs that potentially run asynchronously).

I'm very much a SQL noob so I do ask to please link documentation if necessary or at least describe answers in a google-friendly way.

Comment: As you're going to be translating from GUID to INT repeatedly (every load to the dwh) you do need to keep the GUIDs Somewhere (you can't discard them, future data will refer to them). I recommend keeping them in the table for which they are a PK and then Also having an integer autoincrement column (a surrogate key) to act as the PK in your DWH. Then, when you load data which uses the GUID as a foreign key, do a join to look up the integer surrogate key and use that instead. Finally, when loading the data into QlikView, just don't include the guid columns.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is the removal of GUID is the major cause of possible shrink to 90mb ? Do you not need GUID to process the Report?
2. Do you strip the relationship and join almost all table into as few table as possible when creating the staging table?

If answer to number 1 and 2 is yes then you do not need GUID and simply need to have a int unique column.

I suggest in select command during creating/inserting staging table you use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for replacing the GUID column with int unique column. This is only going to work if you recreating the staging table each time running the SSIS Script.

If you are simply inserting data to an already existing Staging Table when running SSIS Script then you can just create an [autoincrement primary column](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-define-an-auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server/). When you insert data to Staging Table, do not insert to autoincrement primary column so the column is automatically generating unique int value.